# Is there a way to get an IObjectContextAdapter from an IdentityDbContext in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I am getting the following error..

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Company.Data.SqlDbContext' to type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter'.'

on

```
IObjectContextAdapter adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)db;
```

Where db is my Company.Data.SqlDbContext inheriting from IdentityDbContext

my csproj has the following Package References..

```
<PackageReference Include="Accord.MachineLearning" Version="3.8.0"/>
<PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.4.4"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.1"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos" Version="5.0.1"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.1"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.1"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.1"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="5.0.1"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="5.0.1"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.1"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch" Version="5.0.1"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="5.0.1"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="4.2.0"/>
<PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.11.7"/>
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies" Version="5.0.1"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.16.0"/>
<PackageReference Include="Clipper" Version="6.4.0">
    <NoWarn>NU1701</NoWarn>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="postgrest-csharp" Version="2.0.1"/>
<PackageReference Include="realtime-csharp" Version="2.0.0"/>
<PackageReference Include="gotrue-csharp" Version="2.1.4"/>
<PackageReference Include="MimeMapping" Version="1.0.1.37">
    <NoWarn>NU1701</NoWarn>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="JWT" Version="8.1.3"/>
```

I have read that IdentityDbContext inherits from DbContext which implements IObjectContextAdapter however I cannot cast my Context which inherits from IdentityDbContext to either DbContext or IObjectContextAdapter.

Thanks for reading and any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the reading you have done is based on EF6 and not EF Core.
Your csproj shows you are using EF Core.

If you trying to access the state of the entities being managed by the DbContext, you can use the ChangeTracker on the DbContext in EF Core instead of the ObjectContext in EF6.

If you're using Visual Studio you can keep following the definitions of the base class from SqlDbContext to IdentityDbContext to DbContext.  You'll see that DbContext (in EF Core) does not implement that IObjectContextAdapter interface.

Here's a good write up ... https://long2know.com/2016/07/porting-ef6-to-ef7-or-ef-core/